# display: flex in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to convert my nav item stacked into row by using flex property and add other flex property but due to some reason it is not effecting. Here is my code
HTML

```
<div class="item">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    color: #648;
}
.item ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
} 
.item {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    /* height: 65px; */
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.item li {
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.item {
    display: -webkit-flex;  
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;  
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/z28qv08L/

Comment: I think you want the flexbox container to be the `ul` instead of the `div`. So use `<ul class="item">` instead of `<div class="item">`.

Comment: ...or change your CSS to `.item ul { ... }`  http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/sdb8hunc/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `display: flex;` to the `<ul>` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/536k9kte/

Answer (score 1):

you want to align the `li` items in `row`. so you need to add `display:flex` to direct parent element. In this case `ul` is parent element. and you can give equal space using `justify-content:space-between;`.

```css
div.item ul{display:flex;justify-content:space-between;width: 50%;flex-direction: row; }
ul{list-style-type: none}
```

```html
<div class="item">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```